# Calculating spatial averages for each country after spatial join

Tags: python, spatial, geopandas, reverse-geocoding, shapely

Hello I am using the following code at the bottom to extract countries from coordinates. Please see the following url which provides a more detailed explanation of the code: [Extracting countries from NetCDF data using geopandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69979666/extracting-countries-from-netcdf-data-using-geopandas).

My main variable/value is the monthly mean pdsi value from: https://psl.noaa.gov/data/gridded/data.pdsi.html. The image below represents a portion of the visualization created by the code below. The shaded squares represent the spatial regions of pdsi values, which is overlapping a shapefile of the world.

[image: Country example]

From the image of Belgium, you can see that the 4 squares that touch the land area of Belgium are also touching other countries. If I attribute the base values to the Belgium, I believe this overestimates the mean pdsi values. Especially when considering the bottom two squares barely touch Belgium, the weight of these values when calculating the mean should be significantly lower. Thus, is there a way to incorporate some sort of weighted average where the area of each square within a country can be used as the weight to adjust each pdsi value? Additionally, I would like to standardize this process not only for Belgium, but for all countries as well.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

```
import geopandas as gpd
import numpy as np
import plotly.express as px
import requests
from pathlib import Path
from zipfile import ZipFile
import urllib
import shapely.geometry
import xarray as xr

# download NetCDF data...
# fmt: off
url = "https://psl.noaa.gov/repository/entry/get/pdsi.mon.mean.selfcalibrated.nc?entryid=synth%3Ae570c8f9-ec09-4e89-93b4-babd5651e7a9%3AL2RhaV9wZHNpL3Bkc2kubW9uLm1lYW4uc2VsZmNhbGlicmF0ZWQubmM%3D"
f = Path.cwd().joinpath(Path(urllib.parse.urlparse(url).path).name)
# fmt: on

if not f.exists():
    r = requests.get(url, stream=True, headers={"User-Agent": "XY"})
    with open(f, "wb") as fd:
        for chunk in r.iter_content(chunk_size=128):
            fd.write(chunk)
ds = xr.open_dataset(f)
pdsi = ds.to_dataframe()
pdsi = pdsi.reset_index().dropna()  # don't care about places in oceans...

# use subset for testing... last 5 times...
pdsim = pdsi.loc[pdsi["time"].isin(pdsi.groupby("time").size().index[-5:])]

# create geopandas dataframe
gdf = gpd.GeoDataFrame(
    pdsim, geometry=pdsim.loc[:, ["lon", "lat"]].apply(shapely.geometry.Point, axis=1)
)

# make sure that data supports using a buffer...
assert (
    gdf["lat"].diff().loc[lambda s: s.ne(0)].mode()
    == gdf["lon"].diff().loc[lambda s: s.ne(0)].mode()
).all()
# how big should the square buffer be around the point??
buffer = gdf["lat"].diff().loc[lambda s: s.ne(0)].mode().values[0] / 2
gdf["geometry"] = gdf["geometry"].buffer(buffer, cap_style=3)

# Import shapefile from geopandas
path_to_data = gpd.datasets.get_path("naturalearth_lowres")
world_shp = gpd.read_file(path_to_data)

# the solution... spatial join buffered polygons to countries
# comma separate associated countries
gdf = gdf.join(
    world_shp.sjoin(gdf.set_crs("EPSG:4326"))
    .groupby("index_right")["name"]
    .agg(",".join)
)
gdf["time_a"] = gdf["time"].dt.strftime("%Y-%b-%d")

# simplest way to test is visualise...
px.choropleth_mapbox(
    gdf,
    geojson=gdf.geometry,
    locations=gdf.index,
    color="pdsi",
    hover_data=["name"],
    animation_frame="time_a",
    opacity=.3
).update_layout(
    mapbox={"style": "carto-positron", "zoom": 1},
    margin={"l": 0, "r": 0, "t": 0, "b": 0},
)
```

Comment: This sounds like a scientific question, not a coding question. SO is suitable for questions where you state your methodology and you need help coding up that methodology

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- using https://geopandas.org/en/stable/docs/reference/api/geopandas.GeoSeries.intersection.html you can get part of grid that intersects with country polygon
- using area, you can calculate proportion of overlap
- from this I have generated two visualisations

  1. show countries a grid overlaps and how much it overlaps
  2. aggregate to countries using a weighted average plus calculate other measures that can be used for transparency

I do not know if this is mathematically / scientifically sound to aggregate PDSI in this way (either means or weighted averages).  This does demonstrate how to get results your question requests.

```
# the solution... spatial join buffered polygons to countries
# plus work out overlap between PDSI grid and country.  Area of each grid is constant...
gdf_c = (
    world_shp.sjoin(gdf.set_crs("EPSG:4326"))
    .merge(
        gdf.loc[:, "geometry"],
        left_on="index_right",
        right_index=True,
        suffixes=("", "_pdsi"),
    )
    .assign(
        overlap=lambda d: (
            d["geometry"]
            .intersection(gpd.GeoSeries(d["geometry_pdsi"], crs="EPSG:4326"))
            .area
            / (buffer * 2) ** 2
        ).round(3)
    )
)

# comma separate associated countries and a list of overlaps
gdf_pdsi = gdf.loc[:, ["geometry", "time", "pdsi"]].join(
    gdf_c.groupby("index_right").agg({"name": ",".join, "overlap": list})
)
gdf_pdsi["time_a"] = gdf_pdsi["time"].dt.strftime("%Y-%b-%d")

# simplest way to test is visualise...
fig_buf = px.choropleth_mapbox(
    gdf_pdsi,
    geojson=gdf_pdsi.geometry,
    locations=gdf_pdsi.index,
    color="pdsi",
    hover_data=["name", "overlap"],
    animation_frame="time_a",
    opacity=0.3,
).update_layout(
    mapbox={"style": "carto-positron", "zoom": 1},
    margin={"l": 0, "r": 0, "t": 0, "b": 0},
)

fig_buf
```

[image]

```
import pandas as pd

# prepare data to plot by country
df_pdsi = (
    gdf_c.groupby(["name", "time"])
    .apply(
        lambda d: pd.Series(
            {
                "weighted_pdsi": (d["pdsi"] * d["overlap"]).sum() / d["overlap"].sum(),
                "unweighted_pdsi": d["pdsi"].mean(),
                "min_pdsi": d["pdsi"].min(),
                "max_pdsi": d["pdsi"].max(),
                "min_overlap": d["overlap"].min(),
                "max_overlap": d["overlap"].max(),
                "size_pdsi": len(d["pdsi"]),
                # "pdsi_list":[round(v,2) for v in d["pdsi"]]
            }
        )
    )
    .reset_index()
)
df_pdsi["time_a"] = df_pdsi["time"].dt.strftime("%Y-%b-%d")
fig = px.choropleth_mapbox(
    df_pdsi,
    geojson=world_shp.set_index("name").loc[:, "geometry"],
    locations="name",
    color="weighted_pdsi",
    hover_data=df_pdsi.columns,
    animation_frame="time_a",
    opacity=0.3,
).update_layout(
    mapbox={"style": "carto-positron", "zoom": 1},
    margin={"l": 0, "r": 0, "t": 0, "b": 0},
)
fig
```

[image]

Comment: Hi @RobRaymond, thank you very much for your help again. Your code ran successfully, but when I try to export the df_pdsi dataframe to a csv file only year 2014 is listed. I need to have the full time series data and I am having trouble figuring out how to add the full set of years. Could you please help me with this?

Comment: `# use subset for testing... last 5 times...
pdsim = pdsi.loc[pdsi["time"].isin(pdsi.groupby("time").size().index[-5:])]
` in original answer

Comment: I apologize, I am not sure where to include this code? I did include this code in the beginning and ran the new code you posted. I am supposed to use this same code a 2nd time before running the df_pdsi code?

Comment: take a look though the code you posted in the question....  you will see there is a line early on that is explicitly commented *use subset for testing... last 5 times...*   remove / comment this line and it will work with all data.  this is a pandas filter https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/getting_started/intro_tutorials/03_subset_data.html.  I think the graphs will not work with all dates,  too much data for plotly / too many dates in animation