# Sum dataframe values in for loop inside a for loop

Tags: python, dataframe, geopandas

I have a `large polygon` file, `small polygon` file and `points` file. What I do here is loop through large polygons to find which small polygons intersect. Then calculate the area of each small polygon within the large one. And then I loop through the small polygons to find points statistics in each of them.

I have found `number_of_somethin` value in each small polygon. And the question would be how to can I sum all `number_of_somethin` small polygons values within the large polygon and store the results in original `large_polygon` file as a new column, let's say `large_polygon['smth_sum']`?

With `df_res_2.loc[idx, 'smth'] = number_of_somethin` I get number_of_somethin values in each small polygon inside the large ones. Now I need to sum them in `large_polygon['smth_sum']`

*Note:*  *FID* is the id for large polygons and *ID* is the id for small polygons

```
import geopandas as gpd

small_polygon = gpd.read_file(r'R:\...\small.shp')
large_polygon = gpd.read_file(r'R:\...\large.shp')
points = gpd.read_file(r'R:\...\points.shp')

SmallJoin =gpd.sjoin(small_polygon, large_polygon)[['FID', 'ID', 'someValue','geometry']]

for i in large_polygon.index:
    df_i = SmallJoin[SmallJoin['FID'] == i]

    # i do something here, f.e. calculate small polgyon area
    df_res = gpd.overlay(large_polygon, df_i, how='intersection')
    df_res['area'] = round((df_res.apply(lambda row: row.geometry.area, axis=1)), 4)

    # now i know area for each small polygon within large polygon
    df_res_2 = df_res[df_res['FID_1'] == i]

    # now point statistics in small polygons
    PointsJoin =gpd.sjoin(points, df_res)[['ID','someAttribute', 'someAttribute2','geometry']]

    for idx, val in df_res_2['ID'].items():
        df_idx = PointsJoin[PointsJoin['ID'] == val]
        number_of_somethin = df_idx ['someAttribute'] + 121 + df_idx['someAttribute2']
        df_res_2.loc[idx, 'smth'] = number_of_somethin
```

I had a few ideas how to do this, but none of them are not wokring, so I assume that there is some other way.

```
large_polygon.loc[i, 'smth_sum'] = df_res_2['smth']
large_polygon.loc[i, 'smth_sum'] = df_res_2['smth'].sum()

large_polygon['smth_sum'] = large_polygon[large_polygon['FID'] == df_res_2['FID_1'].sum()]
```

Comment: It's difficult to really demonstrate without sample data.  Can you but your sample shape files on GitHub.  I would expect that all of this can be achieved using **pandas** and `groupby()` effectively same technique that is used to calculate overlaps in this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70051743/calculating-spatial-averages-for-each-country-after-spatial-join/70071985#70071985

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- you describe three *GeoDataFrame*

  1. large - have used country boundaries for this
  2. small - have used UTM zone boundaries for this
  3. point - have used randomly generated points that mostly overlap 2
- you define that you want two outputs for each large geometry (country here)

  - *area* - sum of **intersection** *area* of each *small* geometry
  - *value* - sum of value of *points* that is within a *small* geometry that spatially joins to a *large* geometry
- all of the above can be achieved with spatial joins and **pandas** `merge()` and `groupby()`
- to make this clearer - also included a way to visualise all of this

```
import geopandas as gpd
import shapely.geometry
import requests
import numpy as np
import plotly.express as px

# get some sample data....
# fmt: off
gdf_utm = gpd.GeoDataFrame.from_features(requests.get("https://opendata.arcgis.com/datasets/b294795270aa4fb3bd25286bf09edc51_0.geojson").json()).set_crs("EPSG:4326")
gdf_countries = gpd.read_file(gpd.datasets.get_path("naturalearth_lowres"))

large_polygon = gdf_countries.loc[lambda d: d["iso_a3"].isin(["BEL", "LUX", "NLD", "DEU", "AUT"])]
# large_polygon.boundary.plot()

small_polygon = gpd.sjoin(gdf_utm, large_polygon).loc[:, gdf_utm.columns].groupby(["FID", "ZONE"]).first().reset_index()
# fmt: on

# some points within geometry of small_polygon
b = small_polygon.total_bounds
POINTS = 10
points = gpd.GeoDataFrame(
    geometry=[
        shapely.geometry.Point(x, y)
        for x, y in zip(
            np.random.uniform(*b[[0, 2]], POINTS),
            np.random.uniform(*b[[1, 3]], POINTS),
        )
    ],
    data={"value": np.arange(POINTS)},
    crs="EPSG:4326",
)

# spatial small to large with geometry from large
SmallJoin = gpd.sjoin(small_polygon, large_polygon).merge(
    large_polygon["geometry"],
    left_on="index_right",
    right_index=True,
    suffixes=("", "_large"),
)
SmallJoin["area"] = SmallJoin.intersection(gpd.GeoSeries(SmallJoin["geometry_large"])).area

# get sums of area of overlap and sum of values from points
Final = (
    SmallJoin.rename(columns={"index_right": "index_large"})
    .sjoin(points)
    .groupby("index_large")
    .agg({"area": "sum", "value": "sum", "geometry_large": "first"})
)
```

#### output

| index_large | area | value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 114 | 24.6382 | 25 |
| 121 | 90.3565 | 45 |
| 128 | 0.603031 | 20 |
| 129 | 7.65999 | 20 |
| 130 | 10.5284 | 20 |

#### visualise it

```
px.choropleth_mapbox(
    Final,
    geojson=gpd.GeoSeries(Final["geometry_large"]),
    locations=Final.index,
    color="value",
    hover_data=["area"],
).add_traces(
    px.scatter_mapbox(
        points,
        lat=points.geometry.y,
        lon=points.geometry.x,
        color="value",
    )
    .update_traces(marker_coloraxis="coloraxis2", marker_size=10)
    .data
).update_layout(
    mapbox={
        "style": "carto-positron",
        "center": {"lon": sum(b[[0, 2]]) / 2, "lat": sum(b[[1, 3]]) / 2},
        "zoom": 3,
        "layers": [{"source": small_polygon.__geo_interface__, "type": "line"}],
    },
    coloraxis2={
        "colorbar": {"x": -0.1, "title": "scatter"},
        "colorscale": [[0, "blue"], [1, "blue"]],
    },
    coloraxis={"colorscale": [[0, "white"], [1, "green"]]},
    margin={"l": 0, "r": 0, "t": 0, "b": 0},
)
```

[image]